# Can't load multiple property files in spring's application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

I have three property files placed in a resource folder in classpath. The problem i am facing is while i am able to load invidual files separately i am unable to load them when they are declared together.

Please see the XML below:

```xml
<bean name="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames"    value="resources\label"/>

</bean>
                                                                                                                                                                          This is working but the XML given below isn't:
```

```xml
<bean name="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames"    value="resources\label,resources\button,resources\messages"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

I wish to declared them together as I wish to use a single bean to access all three files. Help required!

Comment: Where are your files located?

Comment: in a folder namely resources placed under classpath.

Comment: Try a `resources/label` instead of `resources\label` and also prefix with `classpath:` or `classpath*:` depending if they are packaged in a separate jar or not.

Comment: i did  try all these options and found  only `resources\label` to work. But when i am trying to append other files along with it,its not working anymore.

Comment: Then the error must be correct and there is no such message. I use it with even more files without problems and have used it on several occasions.

Comment: but as i said when i am mentioning just one file it is working alright. Could you post the full code using `classpath` or `classpath*:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer . It should be like this 
 `

```
          <property name="basenames">
          <list>
               <value>classpath:resources\label</value>
               <value>classpath:resources\button</value>
               <value>classpath:resources\messages</value>
          </list>
          </property>

       </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```xml
<property name="basenames">
    <list>
        <value>resources\label</value>
        <value>resources\button</value>
        <value>resources\messages</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'selectlineofbusiness' for locale 'en_US'. Seems the file is inaccessible and hence the key could not be read.